# How to choose optimizer and learning rate for hyperparameter training in keras-tuner

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

I would like to do hyperparameter training using
the kerastuner framework.

How can I choose an optimizer **and** different learning rates
which can be passed to the optimizers.
This is my `model.compile()`method.

```
        model.compile(
        loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=hp.Choice('optimizer', values=['adam', 'adagrad', 'SGD']),
        metrics=['accuracy']
        )
```

That code only picks one of the optimizers
at a time and would use the default learning rates.
I want to pass learning rates with `hp.Float('lrate', min_value=1e-4, max_value=1e-2, sampling='LOG')`
to each optimizer. How can i nest them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with this:

```
# Select optimizer    
optimizer=hp.Choice('optimizer', values=['adam', 'adagrad', 'SGD']

# Conditional for each optimizer
if optimizer == 'adam':
   .....
elif optimizer == 'adagrad':
   .....
elif optimizer == 'SGD':
   .....

# Now compile your model with previous param
model.compile(
    loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=['accuracy']
    )
```